# Write Verification to Cordova BLE error using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using the cordova-plugin-ble-central to connect to a v.bttn device via Bluetooth BLE.

I am able to scan it, and connect to it.  But I need send a verification code within 30 seconds.  So using the information on the Github plugin site I used the write command.

This is what the command looks like:

```
    var data = new Uint8Array(1);
    data[0] = '80:BE:F5:AC:FF';
    ble.write(bttnid, 'fffffff0-00f7-4000-b000-000000000000', '0xFFFFFFF5-00F7-4000-B000-000000000000', data.buffer, deviceVerifiedSuccess, deviceVerifiedFailed);
```

From the plugin docs, this is how the query should look:

```
ble.write(device_id, service_uuid, characteristic_uuid, value, success, failure);
```

I get the device id, and make that into a global variable.  Below is the documentation from the manufacture v.bttn.

> V.BTTN Verification (UUID: 0xFFFFFFF5-00F7-4000-B000-000000000000)
>   The V.BTTN Verification Characteristic enables apps to communicate with V.BTTN. Verification key value is 80:BE:F5:AC:FF. Refer to section 5, Connecting to V.BTTN for details requirements for connecting to V.BTTN

[image]

What is i am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table says the length of the verification code is 5 bytes, so try sending 80:BE:F5:AC:FF as bytes.

```
var verificationKey = new Uint8Array([0x80, 0xbe, 0xf5, 0xac, 0xff]);

ble.write(bttnid, 
    'fffffff0-00f7-4000-b000-000000000000', // v.bttn service
    'fffffff5-00f7-4000-b000-000000000000', // verification characteristic
    verificationKey.buffer,
    function() { console.log('wrote verification key'); }, 
    function(reason) { console.log('Error sending verification key ' + reason); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you again Don, huge help you have been!